# grid en taiwind

Tags: laravel, tailwind

Buen día, estoy trbajando en un proyecto en Laravel 8 (mix) con tailwindcss v3, es una instalacion limpia (spatie, tailwinds y firewire ) y me encontré con un problema en los grid, pues necesito que en pantallas pequeñas ocupe todo el ancho y de medianas para arriba 3 y 9 si voy al siguiente link (Demo Tailwindcss):  https://play.tailwindcss.com/qxQCNJNVv0

y pruebo el diseño que quiero que es éste:

```
Funciona:
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 md:grid-cols-12 gap-2">
  <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-4 bg-cyan-500 p-4">
    col span 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-8 bg-cyan-500 p-4">
    col span 4
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-span-12 bg-cyan-500 mt-2 p-4">
    col 12
  </div>
```

tal como se aprecia en imagenes

Pantalla mediana hacia arriba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pantalla pequeña:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi layout es el siguiente

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/toastr/toastr.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/select2/css/select2.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') }}">

              @livewireStyles

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('vendor/toastr/toastr.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('vendor/select2/js/select2.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('vendor/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js') }}" defer></script>
  

    </head>
     <body>   
         {{-- menu navegacion        --}}
         @livewire('navigation-menu')

            <div class="grid grid-cols-6 md:grid-cols-12 gap-2">
                <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-4 bg-cyan-500 p-4">
                  col span 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-6 md:col-span-8 bg-cyan-500 p-4">
                  col span 4
                </div>
              </div>
        

            
                     
          

        @stack('modals')

        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

Como se ve en navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, luego de varias reviiones, el css compilado estaba mal, faltaban archivos

Comment: Esto en realidad parece mas un comentario que una respuesta, por favor lea [answer] ¿cuáles archivos faltaban?